# Куда поместить вспомогательные функции?

Tags: javascript, ооп, функции, классы

Стараюсь соблюдать ООП, чтобы все красиво.
Но помимо функций, которые явно относятся к объектам
(или к классам, static), есть общие утилиты, математические и служебные типа:

```
rndInt  = (mn, mx) => 
    Math.floor(Math.random() * (mx - mn + 1) + mn);
```

и более специфические. Стоит ли сделать отдельный класс Utils и поместить их туда как static?

Comment: Вполне можно да.... или папка Helpers и классы Math, String, Array  и пр.... ну или как-то так, чтобы было по принадлежности классы разбиты

Answer (score -3):

> есть общие утилиты

> rndInt

кмк для таких целей создавать классы не имеет смысла, обычных объектов более чем достаточно. если подобных функций немного то и одного объекта может хватить.

но вообще, если хотите расти в командного игрока, лучше постараться не велосипедить все эти функции, а взять хотя бы вездесущий jQuery и использовать его функции.
после того как привыкните к подобному формату разработки, можно будет попробовать что то по серьёзнее и свежее:

**реакт, светлэ, надо, вий, отгуляр** ну и вот это вот всё(когда соберетесь браться за это, вбейте в гугле "js фреймворки", всех названий все равно не знаю, да и вдруг к тому времени топ изменится)